# Count similar values in php array of array and add unique in a new array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I've got problems with some algo on a php array. Here is a kind of example of what I get after a grep on several logs files and store it in an array. It can be longer, each element is the result of a grep depending of the number of logs file in folder).

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_indexes

            [1] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_tree_categories

            [2] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/add_device

            [3] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/check_email

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => : [GET] /api_v2/resources/categories

            [1] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_indexes

            [2] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_tree_categories

            [3] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/add_device

            [4] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/check_email

            [5] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/facebook_login

            [6] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/login

            [7] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/register


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_indexes

            [1] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_tree_categories

            [2] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/add_device

            [3] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/facebook_login

            [4] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/login

        )
)
```

I want to count all key occurrences before deleting them and get a new array where there is unique key and the count.  Example:

```
        (
            [name] => : [GET] /api_v2/resources/categories
            [count] => : 2

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_indexes
            [count] => : 3

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_tree_categories
            [count] => : 5

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/add_device
            [count] => : 2 

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/check_email
            [count] => : 2

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/facebook_login
            [count] => : 6

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/login
            [count] => : 2

            [name] => : [POST] /api_v2/users/register
            [count] => : 2

        )
```

Comment: The array you wish to have is impossible to create. `name` and `count` keys can only occur once.

Comment: is `[POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_indexes` a string? (PLUS: the result should be like a map of (name => count) not the array you mentioned!

Comment: Please show the attempt(s) that you have made and describe the result and how it differs from what you want.  Right now it simply looks like you're asking us to do your work for you (even though that may not be the case)

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the arrays and count the values:

```
$result = array_count_values(array_merge(...$array));
```

Should yield something like:

```
Array (
            [ : [GET] /api_v2/resources/categories] => 2
            [ : [POST] /api_v2/resources/new_service_indexes] => 3
)
```

The result array that you show isn't possible unless it's also two-dimensions.  To do that:

```
foreach($result as $key => $val) {
    $new_result[] = ['name' => $key, 'count' => $val];
}
```

But it would probably be easier just to merge the arrays while executing the `grep`, but you don't show that code.  You could ask another question with that code to get a better array format or this end result.